# Flex Monitor Server Requests

Tags: apache-flex

I have the System below

one server
20 clients (could increase)

the clients display a webpage that has the flex swf file. it will display a list. it will poll server every 1sec for any changes in the data. if there's any, it will refresh the data.

the polling is handled using a url that returns json object.

Now i want to have an webapplication that i can use to see the current status of all the monitors on the network

any smart solution?

Comment: You need a backend application and not only a url that returns a JSON object to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially have all the monitor apps connect to a NetConnectionGroup along with your status check app. They could then post pings and health checks into the group, and if your status check app is also connected it could report those statuses (this of course doesn't help if one of the monitors has crashed or not connected, but you'll have that problem with any solution!)

Comment: Hi Gregor. Thanks for the response. Can you xplain a bit more or any references. i'm new to flex.

Comment: after some research i found this url http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=13920;docIndex=1;illustIndex=0 but having a hard time understanding this. esp this url <mx:AMFChannel url="http://tourdeflex.adobe.com:8080/lcds-samples/messagebroker/amfpolling"/>
 what is in there?

Comment: That particular line of code sets up the location that can be used by services (RemoteObject or HTTPService for example). I'd be careful about looking at anything to do with LCDS, it's *extremely* expensive!

Comment: Cirrus on Adobe Labs is an Adobe-hosted service. we need something that we can put it on our server as this network will not be connected to internet

Comment: waht do you think about weborb

Comment: There's a version that just does FP to FP without a server if you are all on the same LAN

Comment: fp to fp is it something like this http://www.flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html

Comment: P2P nodes can communicate with one another without using Stratus. Accomplishing this requires the nodes to be on a Local Area Network, since connecting in this manner requires LAN discovery." from here... http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_rtmfp_groups.html